# I am not getting my Stored Procedure in drop down in STORED PROCEDURE ACTIVITY of Azure Data Factory

Tags: database, azure, stored-procedures, azure-data-factory, etl

I am using Azure Data Factory for my ETL pipelines, I have created Stored Procedure in my database.
I have that Stored Procedure in both (Azure Data Studio and Azure Portal).
But when I am trying to use stored procedure in ADF, I am getting nothing in drop down.
I have checked that my linked service is fine, even I have created new one also but no luck.
I got 2 Stored Procedures in my DB, But none of them are visible in STORED PROCEDURE ACTIVITY in ADF.
Any Idea what would be the problem here.?

Below is the image of the issue I am facing.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gf2Sy.png)

I tried creating a fresh linked service, but no luck.
I tried to manually enter Stored Procedure name but no luck.

Comment: Are you using the same user for connecting DB in Azure Data Studio and ADF?

Comment: Yes, Same User.
It is my email on both platforms.

Comment: Did you check the db in linked service is it that which is having stored procedures?

Comment: Yes,
I checked it twice. 
Even I created a new Linked Service for same database but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To view the stored procedure from azure Data factory stored procedure activity make sure you have configured correctly ac below:

- Make sure you are using correct user to authenticate from Azure Data Factory.
- Make sure the stored procedure is exist on the data base.
- Make sure the user you are using to authenticate has execute permission on respective stored procedure.

```sql
GRANT  EXECUTE  ON  OBJECT::SACHEMA.storedprocedure TO ROlE;
```

[image]